# Create a new type of object in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I'm just starting with Oracle, and I need to create a new type of object, for example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tipo1 IS OBJECT (
Primernombre CHAR(10),
Segundonombre CHAR(10),
NumeroCel Number(21),
MEMBER FUNCTION Numero RETURN Number);

CREATE TABLE T1( Code VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, Nombres Tipo1, CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY (Code) );

INSERT INTO T1 (Code,Nombres) 
VALUES (1554,Tipo1('Nombre1','SegN1',774744));
INSERT INTO T1 (Code,Nombres) 
VALUES (1555,Tipo1('Nombre2','SegN2',774746));
INSERT INTO T1 (Code,Nombres) 
VALUES (1556,Tipo1('Nombre3','SegN3',774146));


CREATE 
OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Tipo1 IS MEMBER FUNCTION Numero RETURN Number IS x Number;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        c.Nombres.NumeroCel INTO x 
    FROM
        T1 c;
RETURN (x);
END;
END;

SELECT c.Nombres.Numero() FROM T1 c;
```

However when there is more than one record I get this error:

```
ORA-01422: Exact recovery returns a greater number of rows than requested.
```

In what way can I get more records out? I thought of a FOR, but I do not know how it would be used in this case.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqYmG.png)

Comment: Really what I need is to create an object type address to then create the tables, use it and when you consult you can only take the street or the number or the city

Comment: You want to be able to ask any instance of your `tipo1` object to get the `numerocel` values for every row in your object table? Is that a useful thing to do?

Comment: It really is also a bit in didactic terms, how would something like that be done? .Also the question ba as to how these composite attributes are treated, If I want them to be saved as a single attribute where inside the structure is and in some queries I just want to get a part

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. If you have two rows in the table, what are you expecting your `SELECT c.Nombres.Numero() FROM T1 c` to return? Your member function suggests you want to the function to return the `numero` values of *every* row (as it's querying the table itself), implying that your query should return every `numero` in the table but for every row. So if the table had two rows you'd see 4 results; if you had 3 rows you'd see 9 results. That doesn't sound right. Please add more sample data and expected results to your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your member function is just to get the field value for that object instance then you don't need it at all; you can refer directly to the object's fields.

Recreating your example without the member function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tipo1 IS OBJECT (
  Primernombre CHAR(10),
  Segundonombre CHAR(10),
  NumeroCel Number(21)
);
/

CREATE TABLE T1( Code VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, Nombres Tipo1, CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY (Code) );

INSERT INTO T1 (Code,Nombres) 
VALUES (1554,Tipo1('Nombre1','SegN1',774744));
INSERT INTO T1 (Code,Nombres) 
VALUES (1555,Tipo1('Nombre2','SegN2',774746));
INSERT INTO T1 (Code,Nombres) 
VALUES (1556,Tipo1('Nombre3','SegN3',774146));
```

then you can query just that field:

```
SELECT c.Nombres.NumeroCel FROM T1 c;

NOMBRES.NUMEROCEL
-----------------
           774744
           774746
           774146
```

or a combination of columns and object fields:

```
SELECT c.code, c.Nombres.Primernombre, c.Nombres.Segundonombre, c.Nombres.NumeroCel
FROM T1 c;

CODE     NOMBRES.PR NOMBRES.SE NOMBRES.NUMEROCEL
-------- ---------- ---------- -----------------
1554     Nombre1    SegN1                 774744
1555     Nombre2    SegN2                 774746
1556     Nombre3    SegN3                 774146
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I'm just guessing, but I think you might be overcomplicating things, and you just want a normal type body member function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Tipo1 
IS 
  MEMBER FUNCTION Numero RETURN Number IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN NumeroCel;
  END;
END;
/
```